# Writing multiple wav files with scipy

Tags: python, audio, scipy

I currently have a list containing the data and sample rate of multiple audio files in form of a tuple, as follows:

```
list = [(numpy array audio1, sample rate audio1), (numpy array audio2, sample rate audio2) ... etc.]
```

I am now trying to use that data to save a wave file for each tuple with the following code:

```
for i in list:
    counter = 1
    scipy.io.wavfile.write(filename = "file"+str(counter), rate= i[1], data=i[0])
    counter +=1
```

It turns out however that only the first file gets saved: file1 and then nothing happens anymore. Would appreciate if you guys know where the problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting your `counter` in each step of your loop back to 1. You need to move the statement `counter=1` before the loop. Alternatively consider using `enumerate`:

```
for counter, i in enumerate(mylist, 1):
    scipy.io.wavfile.write(filename = "file"+str(counter), rate= i[1], data=i[0])
```